# Background-image moves when zooming also can't align text in a table

Tags: php, html, css

That's how the page looks like currently: [http://i.imgur.com/nEHLFUX.png[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Q3x.png)   and there are couple of bugs that I would love you to help me with. 2 main ones I want the spell names to be aligned to the right next to little icons of spells and second of all there is a background picture and when I zoom the site out it moves downwards and to the left and I want it to always stay at the same place.

Now code:

```
class spell {
function do_spell($spellicon, $spellname, $spelltext, $changeinpower) {
echo '
<div class="spellrow">
    <table class="spelltable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td ><img class="spellimage" src="/abilities/'.$spellicon.'"></td>
            <td class="spellname">'.$spellname.' - </td>
            <td class="spelldesc">'.$spelltext.'</td>
            <td class="changeinpower"><img  src="/icons/'.$changeinpower.'"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
   ';
 }
}
```

patch.php part

```
$karthus = new splash;
$laywaste1 = new spell;
$laywaste2 = new spell;
$karthus->do_splash('Karthus','cropkarthus','Karthus_0.jpg');
$laywaste1->do_spell('64px-Lay_Waste.jpg','Lay Waste (Q)','Added a new indicator that shows the full area of effect','new.png');
$laywaste2->do_spell('64px-Lay_Waste.jpg','Lay Waste (Q)','Added crit-style combat text and a unique sound effect for double-damage Qs','new.png');
```

Some css:

```
.spellrow {
 width: 900px;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px #cccccc; }
.spelltable {
 width: 100%;}
.spellimage {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 padding-left: 5px;}
.spellname {
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0 5px;
 width: 10px;}
.spelldesc {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.05em;}
.changeinpower {
 width: 60px;}

 /* And now the img in the background part */

 .season2014
 {
 background-color:#f1f1f1;
 background-image: url('/season_graphic/SEASON2014_2.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 20% 50%;
 background-origin: content-box;
 background-position: fixed; }

<body class="season2014";>
```

PS. any kind of mistakes in code I would love you to point out I'm really new to the web-designing thingy

Comment: Is the `CSS` code in your `patch.php` file ? It's better to ask only one question per post, mixing different issues is not very practical for answering...

Comment: nope I have separate file for css code

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the background moving is from the `background-position: fixed`. This `fixed` value is not valid CSS. Try playing with the values available for the property to get the desired effect. More info on the [Mozilla Dev Network for CSS with the `background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

About the name, I haven't seen any `text-align: left` in your CSS, that's maybe what you're looking for in your `.spellname` property. But more than that, the alignment problem comes from the width which is just `width: 10px;` in the `.spellname` property.

Because you fixed the total row width to `900px`, why not use pixels all the way to define all the widths ? Like so:

```
.spellrow {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px #cccccc;
}
.spelltable {
    width: 100%;
}
.spellimage {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.spellname {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px; /* Adapt to your needs */
}
.spelldesc {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.05em;
    text-align: left;
    width: 658px; /* Adapt to your needs */
}
.changeinpower {
    width: 60px;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML code

```
<div class="spellrow">
<table class="spelltable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="spellimage">IMG</td>
        <td class="spellname">Name</td>
        <td class="spelldesc">Text with plenty of info here</td>
        <td class="changeinpower">IMG</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

On a side note, doing *one* table per item is loosing the whole purpose of tables: one item is one **row** of the table. You should have one table per category and each *spell* being a *row* in the according table.

Comment: tried with and without text-align doesn't matter text stays the same and about the background image what would you suggest?

Comment: If you want your background to be fixed, use a fixed value (pixels, em,...) or adapt the image so the default `[0, 0]` position is correct. About the `text-align`, if properly applied to a `<td>` should work...

Comment: See the edit to the post: the problem is that the `td` is only 10px wide. Thus other cells take up the room.

Comment: I've read the edit. Hmm could you tell me then what would be the smartest way to do it? What should the width be then? with flexible with it screws up the spell description

Comment: The problem with having certain widths for everything is that there will be always a long gap between spell name and description when spell name is short

Comment: Then why create two separate columns ? Put both into the same column... And align it left and you won't have the gap. If it's only for styling purposes, use a `<span>`.

Comment: then the 2 line description will get screwed up and the second line will start under the spell name

Comment: Tough cookies eh ? ;) I don't know if what you want to do is achievable in the way you have thought about it...

Comment: http://imgur.com/kBppOQG even after those changes and yea i deleted widths there is still this annoying gap